# scp all files starting with 'file' from a server

Tags: ssh, scp

I use this command to copy all files whose names start with 'file' from a server.
scp -vp me@server:/location/files* ./

But i got a 'No Match' error. probably Concerning the '*' in the command.
How can i protect the '*' for ssh to understand that this refers to a list of files and not taking it as a filename.

Thx
August

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The shell itself is expanding the `*`. You can escape this by quoting it or using backslashes to prevent the shell interpreting it and instead passing it directly to `scp`:

```
scp -vp me@server:/location/files\*
```

Comment: For others wondering what the `-vp` options do like I was: **-v** Verbose mode. Causes scp to print debugging messages about its progress. **-p**: Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file. https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

Answer (score 1):

if you want files started with file then it should be

```
scp me@server:/location/file* .
```

not

> files*

Comment: btw, scp does support wild card, so * works, more info read http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php